# How to capture the value of an input field if the id of the input field is comma separated?(816,20735)

Tags: jquery

I have a legacy application where the id of the input field is coming as(818,201735).
Yea, its weired, but I cant change it!
This is how it gets rendered:

```
<input name="816,20735" class="form-control valid-dateonly valid" id="816,20735" maxlength="4000" placeholder="" value="" data-param="816">
```

Possibly I need to use the data-param attribute here, but i need to get it in the context of $(this) and not like this way:

```
$("input[data-param='" + 816+ "']").val("")
```

I can fetch `$(this)[0].id=816,20735`..could not proceed further!Believe I am close!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show more code of jquery.

Comment: if you are getting `$(this)` as the input element then is it not working `$(this).val()`?

Answer (score 0):

use two backslashes to escape the character like comma.

```
$("#816\\,20735").val()
```